# Using SD card from 3 B+ in 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+

I have a SD Card wich works perfectly on my Pi 3 B+ but I want to use it in my other Pi 3 but the Pi doesnt seem to start.
Is there something that needs to be changed to use the same Card for both versions?

Comment: While it is possible to make a SD Card which will only boot on one model (by deleting necessary files) any normal setup will work in all models.

Comment: When you say 'doesn't seem to start' what do you mean? No boot text? What do the blinky lights on the Pi do when you boot? Are you using the same power adapter/peripherals- i.e. just swapping out the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No rep to comment yet, so this goes as answer.

This is generally a bad idea to use the same SD card swapping between devices, as each of them has its own configuration - despite the same system. Devices differ by on-board components id, or even might be different due to newer revision of board. I own 2 rPi 1 B+ and swapping cards is impossible due to errors with boot.